# How do I keep the logo from resizing when on mobile?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I believe what is happening is the image is getting shrinked until it disappears, and I want to keep it the same size even on mobile, and also leveled to the rest of the nav li/hamburger

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    /* --- header -- */

    .navbar-header div.logo {
      margin-top: -1%;
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    .navbar-header div.logo a.navbar-brand {
      padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar-header div.logo a.navbar-brand img {
      width: 6%;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    navbar-nav .navbar-brand {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .navbar-nav .navbar-brand>img {
      padding: 7px 14px;
    }
    /****override navbar height********/

    .navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding-top: 4px !important;
      padding-bottom: 2px !important;
    }

    .navbar {
      min-height: 5px !important
    }
    /*********************************/

    header .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .navbar-default {
      border: none;
    }

    header .navbar-collapse ul.navbar-nav {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    header .navbar-default {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    header .navbar {
      min-height: 32px;
    }

    header .navbar-nav > li {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      padding-top: 5px;
    }

    header .navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      padding-top: 5px;
      margin-left: 2px;
      line-height: 30px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

  </style>

  <header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="logo">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="./img/logo.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="about.php">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div>content</div>

</body>
```

Does anyone know how to keep the logo from disappearing, moving or resizing, while keeping the rest of the website elements responsive?

Comment: Target the logo with your CSS and make it a set size, % isn't going to keep it the same size as it's relative to the parent, also you've got your style rules in the body tag, why don't you have them in the head tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have set your image to a size in %, you will have to change it to a set size. This:

```
.navbar-header div.logo a.navbar-brand img {
  width: 6%;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

should be something like this:

```
.navbar-header div.logo a.navbar-brand img {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```